# How to detect if the user clicks on the empty canvas area

Tags: html, kineticjs

In kinetic js, how to detect if the user clicks on the empty canvas area? Thanks

Comment: Those downvotes are brutal!  You have a very valid question!

Comment: It would be useful if you can post what you have tried (i.e code samples) and Any error messages etc... you will be more likely to get a useful response.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `the empty canvas area`?

Comment: It is just the blank area, no touch on group, shape, line, anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for click events on the stage like this:

```
$(stage.getContent()).on('click', function (event) {
    var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
    var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
    var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
    console.log(mouseX,mouseY);
});
```

Comment: @arwen asked `user clicks on the empty canvas area` but this post, though accepted, does not seem to address that issue. It simply handles the click event and displays the click's coordinates... Key word here being: empty...

Comment: @PaulSasik, I see your point.  But a common KineticJS confusion is that only nodes trigger click events and the stage itself does not trigger click events--the docs are misleading.  I (evidently correctly) assumed that the most common confusion was the gist of the question.  Anyway...thanks!  BTW, Fridley,MN was my old stomping grounds as a youth...Go MinneSnowTa!